# Blank entries in solution explorer which cause visual studio 2015 to crash when clicked

Tags: visual-studio-2015, solution-explorer

I work on around 35/40 different projects, I have one project which when I open it from source control explorer displays blank entries when viewing it in solution explorer. If I click on any of these blank entries in solution explorer visual studio 2015 crashes.

I'm able to access all the files in the solution if I browse to then via source control explorer.

I've tried disabling all my extensions, I've tried running studio in safe mode. Still happens.

Has anyone came across this before or know how to fix it?

[Screenshot of solution explorer with blank entries showing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ov9IF.png)

**Edit:** I've also tried nuking my profile by running devenv.exe /ResetUserData but it still happens when I open this one particular project.